# Error converting from numeric data type to decimal

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Well here is my problem i have a table that contains the following column:

```
asis_doc_minutos decimal(4,1)
```

If i insert the following number (1.5) with a simple insert query it inserts it! BUT
my SProcedure doesn't inserts the data. Here is my Sp:

```
 ALTER procedure [dbo].[insertar_pla_asis_doc]
  @fecha datetime,
  @tema varchar(500),
  @minutos decimal(2,2),
  @cod_docente int,
  @cod_materia varchar(25),
  @cod_seccion int,
  @cod_ciclo int,
  @cod_escuela int
  as
  begin
 insert into pla_asis_doc(asis_doc_fecha, asis_doc_tema,
 asis_doc_fecha_realizo, asis_doc_cod_docente, asis_doc_cod_mat, asis_doc_seccion,
     asis_doc_cod_ciclo, 
 asis_doc_cod_escuela, asis_doc_minutos)
 values (@fecha, @tema, getdate(), @cod_docente, @cod_materia, @cod_seccion,
 @cod_ciclo, @cod_escuela, @minutos);
   end
```

I'm calling this Sp from C# and this is the way i do it:

```
 int valor_devuelto = puente.insertar(fecha, txtTema.Text,
 Convert.ToDecimal(lblHoras.Text), cod_emp, cod_materia, seccion,
 Convert.ToInt32(ciclo.Text), cod_esc);
```

Notice that (lblHoras.Text) is called from a TextBox and so i convert it to Decimal becasue that's what my column expects. That lines calls to a method in another class, which is the one that calls my Sp in my db and where i got the error, here is that code:

```
public int insertar(DateTime fecha, string tema, decimal minutos, int docente, string materia_codigo, int seccion, int ciclo, int escuela_cod)
{
    int valor = 0;
    try
    {
        cn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = cn;                
        cmd.CommandText = "insertar_pla_asis_doc";
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@fecha", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = fecha;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@tema", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tema;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@minutos", System.Data.SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = minutos;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@cod_docente", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = docente;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@cod_materia", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 
        materia_codigo;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@cod_seccion", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = seccion;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@cod_ciclo", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = ciclo;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@cod_escuela", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
        escuela_cod;
        valor = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return valor;
}
```

Everytime i run this code there's an error saying: 
Error al convertir el tipo de datos numeric a decimal. (Error converting ) How can i solve that?

Comment: How is written the value that you want to store as decimal? And what is your locale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parameter in the procedure is declared as

```
@minutos decimal(2,2)
```

It means two numbers, both right of decimal point.

Check this sample:

```
create table #t (d decimal(2,2))
insert #t values (1.5)
```

Increase the size of the parameter.

Comment: While your observation is true, this code raises another kind of exception. Arithmetic overflow while converting numeric to numeric (or something like that) not the error mentioned by the poster.

Comment: Well i don't know what kind of execeptions may raise this, but for me this solution has work perfectly!! (Y) thanks Dean!!

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @dean above was not very accurate.

It will failed as @steve mentioned.

create table #t (d decimal(2,2))
insert #t values (1.5)

the result will be:
*"Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
The statement has been terminated.*"

Correction:

create table #t (d decimal(3,2))
insert #t values (1.5)

Please see explanation below:

---

**Decimal and numeric arguments:**

decimal[ (p[ , s] )] and numeric[ (p[ , s] )]

Fixed precision and scale numbers. When maximum precision is used, valid values are from - 10^38 +1 through 10^38 - 1. The ISO synonyms for decimal are dec and dec(p, s). numeric is functionally equivalent to decimal.
p (precision)
The maximum total number of decimal digits that will be stored, both to the left and to the right of the decimal point. The precision must be a value from 1 through the maximum precision of 38. The default precision is 18.
s (scale)

**The number of decimal digits that will be stored to the right of the decimal point. This number is substracted from p to determine the maximum number of digits to the left of the decimal point. The maximum number of decimal digits that can be stored to the right of the decimal point.** Scale must be a value from 0 through p. Scale can be specified only if precision is specified. The default scale is 0; therefore, 0 <= s <= p. Maximum storage sizes vary, based on the precision.